# Java no such element exception when comparing values?

Tags: java

I'm creating an application that prompts the user for 3 numbers and it will average those numbers entered. But when I get there, it immediately throws a noSuchElementException.

```
    int i1,i2;
    int sum;
    double d1, d2, d3;//declares values input by the user
    double avg; //variable for calculating final result

    System.out.println("Hello out there. \n" //displays information to the user
            + "I will add two numbers for you. \n"
            + "Enter two whole numbers on a line:");

    Scanner keyboardInt = new Scanner(System.in); //Scans for keyboard input
    i1 = keyboardInt.nextInt();
    i2 = keyboardInt.nextInt();
    sum = (i1+i2);
    System.out.println("The sum of those 2 numbers is: \n" + sum + "\n" + 
    "Now enter 3 decimal numbers on a line:");
    keyboardInt.close();

    Scanner keyboardDouble = new Scanner(System.in); //Scans for keyboard input
    d1 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//-\ THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION. ID ASSUME THE OTHER WILL DO THE SAME
    d2 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//stores values entered by the user
    d3 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//-/
    avg = ((float) (d1+d2+d3)/3.0);//adds the sum of the values entered and calculates the average
    keyboardDouble.close();//closes scanner

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00");//formats the inputed number to 2 decimal places

    System.out.println("The average of those three numbers is:");//displays the average of the numbers
    System.out.println(df.format(avg));                         //entered by the user
```

This is where the problem is:

```
Scanner keyboardDouble = new Scanner(System.in); //Scans for keyboard input
d1 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//-\ THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION. ID ASSUME THE OTHER WILL DO THE SAME
d2 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//stores values entered by the user
d3 = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();//-/
avg = ((float) (d1+d2+d3)/3.0);//adds the sum of the values entered and calculates the average
keyboardDouble.close();//closes scanner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [`Scanner#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29)

> Closes this scanner.
>   If this scanner has not yet been closed then **if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked**. If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.

So, when you did `keyboardInt.close();`, it also closed `System.in`. Hence, when you tried to call `.nextDouble()`, there was nothing left for the Scanner to parse into a `double` (as the underlying stream is closed and thus isn't reading anything), and hence the `NoSuchElementException`.

What you can do to solve this is to use one `Scanner` to do all of the reading of user input, and calling `close()` after you're completely done.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `keyboardInt.close()` statement. It closes the underlying InputStream, which is `System.in`. So, when you create `keyboardDouble`, it can't  read anymore, because `System.in` is closed.

So, to solve, use one Scanner, you use for both purposes:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
...
i1 = keyboard.nextInt();
i2 = keyboard.nextInt();
...
d1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
d2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
d3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
```